# Slow browsers with status "Waiting for www.website.com..."

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, performance

I have been having this issue for a while now and I can't stand it anymore. Both my browsers (Firefox & Chrome) sometimes take forever to load pages.

For example, I will type www.Google.com and the status bar will say "Waiting for www.google.com" for about 10 seconds or so then load. However, sometimes it will load instantly. This pattern happens for any site, not just google.com.

I am thinking that this is a Firewall or Router issue since it is happening on both my browsers.

Maybe it's spyware/virus that is causing this issue?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can please help me diagnose and fix this problem.

System:
Windows 8.1
HP Envy TouchSmart 15
16 GB RAM
2.4 GHZ

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've had that happen recently too. I haven't tested this when I had the problem, I will..

Try typing nslookup see if the result comes back fast. Then type the names of some domains, and see how quickly they get resolved. By the latter, you'll know if your DNS resolution is slow.

```
C:\>nslookup<ENTER>
Default Server:  blah.yourisp.net
Address:  212.23.3.100

> dogpile.com<ENTER>
Server:  dns.lb.mbr-roch.zen.net.uk
Address:  212.23.3.100

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    dogpile.com
Address:  67.63.58.147

>
```

And you could try setting your DNS server to a DNS server that Google puts put. 
 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4